# How to make a SharePoint 2010 picture button work in the Read Only view of a list item

Tags: 2010, infopath, custom-list

I am creating a custom form in SharePoint 2010. I also have access to InfoPath 2010 and SharePoint Designer 2010.

In the form I am building, I have control buttons which will activate or deactivate certain sections (I.e. click the "Show" button and the specified section is visible or click the "Hide" button and the section is no longer displayed).

When I create a new item in the list (or when a previous item is opened in the edit mode) the Show/Hide buttons work properly. The problem is that when an existing item is opened and is in the Read Only mode, the Show/Hide buttons are visible , but do not work. They appear as images instead of working buttons.

My purpose is to give certain users Read Only permission to the list, but still allow them to use the Show/Hide buttons to view various sections of the form.

Is there a non-coding solution to this utilizing InfoPath 2010 or Designer 2010?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint lists will have 3 default template pages when you open in designer.

Dispform
Editform
Newform

So based on your choice you can customize in designer or info path for a non code solution. In your case, you should include a script which does the show/hide actions in the disp form - for existing items.

Comment: Hi Kesava. Thank you for your response, but I am not completely understanding it. I see the Dispform.aspx file in Designer, but I do not have permissions needed to do anything with it. When you say that I can "customize in designer or InfoPath", how do I customize Infopath to obtain the results I am wanting?